# Hadoop word count example fails with 'not a SequentialFile'. How set file format?

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to run `hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar aggregatewordcount /data/gutenberg/huckfinn.txt output/guten4` but get an error "huckfinn.txt not a SequenceFile".

I read on [other sites](http://markmail.org/message/h5bfrpigeh5fenbt), and see in the [source of this example file](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/AggregateWordCount.java.html) that there is an argument `textinputformat` that I'm guessing fixes this.  I can't figure out what to specify for it though.

If I run `hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar aggregatewordcount /data/gutenberg/huckfinn.txt output/guten5 2 textinputformat`, I get a different error, "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [mailing list post](http://markmail.org/message/h5bfrpigeh5fenbt) linked from your question, the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object` exception is caused by the example's dependencies not being on the tasktracker's classpath.  You can see this from the full traceback: when I run your second command on my machine, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.examples.AggregateWordCount$WordCountPlugInClass
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.examples.AggregateWordCount$WordCountPlugInClass
    [...]
```

[This post on the Cloudera blog](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) discusses the different methods of providing dependencies to the tasktrackers.

To run the aggregatewordcount example, I used the `-libjars` option:

`hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar aggregatewordcount -libjars hadoop-examples.jar  /data/gutenberg/huckfinn.txt output/guten7 2 textinputformat`

Comment: There is no need to add `-libjars`, the jar file specified with the `jar` option will be automatically copied to all the nodes by the Hadoop framework. If any additional 3rd party jars need to be copied then the `-libjars` option has to be used.

Comment: Turns out Josh is correct with regards to the error I'm getting.  Adding the -libjars fixes the issue for me using Cloudera 3. Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 1):

In the [ValueAggregatorJob](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.21.0/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aggregate/ValueAggregatorJob.java) the following check is done

```
int numOfReducers = 1;
if (args.length > 2) {
  numOfReducers = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}

..............

if (args.length > 3 && 
    args[3].compareToIgnoreCase("textinputformat") == 0) {
  theInputFormat = TextInputFormat.class;
} else {
  theInputFormat = SequenceFileInputFormat.class;
}
```

If `textinputformat` (literal string) is not specified as an argument, then the input format is defaulted to SequenceFileInputFormat, so the `huckfinn.txt not a SequenceFile error`. Also, the reducers is defaulted to 1 if not specified.

Use the following command to run the job

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapred-examples-0.21.0.jar aggregatewordcount /user/praveensripati/input/sample.txt /user/praveensripati/output 2 textinputformat
```

Note that usually the hadoop-mapred-examples-**0.21.0**.jar has a version number in it. This file is in the root of the Hadoop install. Make sure that the file `/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar` present.

For resolving the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object`, please check the log files for a stack trace and post it back.

Comment: Thanks Praveen.  Great eye on noticing this chunk of code.  It helped clarify that my original command was fine after all.  Regarding the missing version number from my jar, my directory has two examples jars, one w/out the version.  In the end, Josh's proposed solution fixed the error I was getting. Thanks for your detailed response though, it helped with my understanding

Comment: Not exactly sure, how it got resolved. -libjars option is for 3rd party s/w. The jar specified by the `hadoop jar` option gets automatically distributed by the Hadoop framework. I was able to successfully run the job without the -libjars option.

Comment: Are you using Cloudera install?  This could be specific issue with Cloudera packages and how they install (I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Maybe, I am using Apache Hadoop on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 0.20.205.0 on Mac OS 10.6 (installed via homebrew).